# Storing Last Launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to store the last launch date of my app. So I did the following:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:today forKey:@"lastLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

However, when I relaunch the app again and print out the object for key `lastLaunch` it shows `null`. Why isn't it storing the date? Am I putting it in the wrong method? I am running it and terminating the app from Xcode.

Comment: to terminate app you should press home button ..put a nslog statement in method to check whether it is called or not

Comment: I did - it works. But why doesn't that method execute when I terminate an app from Xcode? Isn't stopping an app from Xcode just like terminating an app properly from the phone?

Comment: Nopes apple had provided home button to terminate the app in a correct possible way...resignactive and application enters background are only called when home button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applicationWillResignActive: is also called when you receive phone call... 
You can find more info here: 
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

I think that applicationDidEnterBackground is a better place to put your code because user can deny phone call and go back to your app...

And for iOS3 users without multitasking watch for applicationWillTerminate:

Stop in Xcode just kills your application without calling anything...

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is weird in the iPhone simulator. I expect your code to work on an actual device.